# JavaScript: Check if cookie sets, and change image src to random while refreshing and cookie not expires

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Excuse me for the long title. I'm trying to make something simple, function that runs on load, checks if cookie is set - if "it's true", then change the image src randomly, as below:

HTML Code:

```
<img id="photo" src="../photostock/3129_382a101ee6d307dfd34abad8941c35cd_8885.jpg" alt="background" />
```

JS Code:

```
function rand_photo( id ) {
    var q, img, id;
    var random = function(min, max) {
        return Math.Floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) ) + min;
    };
    q = random( 1, 3 );

    var prefix = '../photostock/',
        suffix = '.jpg';

    switch( q ) {
        case 1: 
            img = '3129_382a101ee6d307dfd34abad8941c35cd_8885';
        break;
        case 2: 
            img = '1404_0d03ec48b64b4b65a6820aa5a58a39af_5487';
        break;
        case 3: 
            img = '1292_5d3c0fde3f83d725eb58025a522a6097_5648';
        break;
        default:
            img = '7395_5d3c0fde3f83d725eb58025a522a6097_4191';
    }

    img = prefix + img + suffix;

    document.getElementById( id ).setAttribute( 'src' ) = img;
    // also tried with just ".src =" - didn't worked
}

function check_create_cookie( cookie_name, ident ) {
    if( document.cookie.indexOf( cookie_name ) >= 0 ) {
        rand_photo( ident )
    }
    else {
        document.cookie = cookie_name + '=1; max-age=60';
    }
}

window.onload = check_create_cookie( 'sample_cookie', 'photo' );
```

but for some reason, it's not working...
any thoughts, notes or both?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some typos in your code.

1. Math.Floor does not exist: the correct form is: Math.floor
2. document.getElementById( id ).setAttribute( 'src' ) = img; is wrong.
   The correct form is: document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('src', img);
   For details see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)
3. The last is: window.onload = check_create_cookie( 'sample_cookie', 'photo' );
   Th correct form is well described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

So, the working code is:

```js
function rand_photo(id) {
  var q, img, id;
  var random = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) ) + min;
  };
  q = random( 1, 3 );

  var prefix = '../photostock/',
      suffix = '.jpg';

  switch( q ) {
    case 1:
      img = '3129_382a101ee6d307dfd34abad8941c35cd_8885';
      break;
    case 2:
      img = '1404_0d03ec48b64b4b65a6820aa5a58a39af_5487';
      break;
    case 3:
      img = '1292_5d3c0fde3f83d725eb58025a522a6097_5648';
      break;
    default:
      img = '7395_5d3c0fde3f83d725eb58025a522a6097_4191';
  }

  img = prefix + img + suffix;

  document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('src', img);
  // also tried with just ".src =" - didn't worked
}

function check_create_cookie( cookie_name, ident ) {
  if( document.cookie.indexOf( cookie_name ) >= 0 ) {
    rand_photo( ident )
  }
  else {
    document.cookie = cookie_name + '=1; max-age=60';
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  check_create_cookie( 'sample_cookie', 'photo' );
}
```

```html
<img id="photo" src="../photostock/3129_382a101ee6d307dfd34abad8941c35cd_8885.jpg" alt="background" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = check_create_cookie( 'sample_cookie', 'photo' );
```

This assign *result of the function* not function. correct syntax is

```
window.onload = function(){check_create_cookie( 'sample_cookie', 'photo' );};
```